# How to rotate a list(not 2D) 90 degree clockwise?

Tags: python, list

As a beginner in Python, I think the biggest problem I have is overcomplicating a problem when it can be done a lot simpler. I have not found a solution for a list that is not two-dimensional, hence why I chose to ask.

**Here is an example of what I am trying to do:**

```
# Before
alphabet = ["ABCDEFG",
            "HIJKLMN",
            "OPQRSTU"]
# After
rotated_alphabet = ["OHA",
                    "PIB",
                    "QJC",
                    "RKD",
                    "SLE",
                    "TMF",
                    "UNG"]
```

**What I have done so far:**

```
length_of_column = len(alphabet)
length_of_row = len(alphabet[0])
temp_list = []

x = -1
for i in range(length_of_column):
    while x < length_of_row-1:
        x += 1
        for row in alphabet:
            temp_list.append(row[x])

temp_list = temp_list[::-1]
```

Output

```
print(temp_list)
>>> ['U', 'N', 'G', 'T', 'M', 'F', 'S','L','E','R','K','D','Q','J','C','P','I','B', 'O', 'H', 'A']
```

I need to make the list above in the desired format.

-How would I do this?

-Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: You do really have 2D data. Strings are iterable like lists. You could also just map `list` over each string to get a 2D list. And look up how to transpose a matrix, since that's essentially what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Carcigenicate, I cannot use 2D lists in this situation, as stated in the question

Comment: They stated that your program cannot use a 2D list anywhere? Even if the input is a list of Strings, you're likely able to manipulate the input however you like. Even if you aren't, looking up how to transpose a matrix may still help. You just won't be able to mutate the lists. You'll just need to reassign the strings instead.

Comment: `["".join([l[i] for l in alphabet][::-1]) for i in range(7)]`. The join makes the string from the list created. The `[::-1]` reverse the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `zip` the list of strings, and it will make tuples character by character, then you'll only have to join the tuples in reverse order. Here it is in just one line:

```
rotated_alphabet = [''.join(list(i)[::-1]) for i in zip(*alphabet)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant of @MuhammadAhmad answer will be to use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), as reversed works with iterables, no need to convert to a list.

```
alphabet = ["ABCDEFG",
            "HIJKLMN",
            "OPQRSTU"]

rotated = [''.join(reversed(a)) for a in zip(*alphabet)]
print(rotated)
```

**Output**

```
['OHA', 'PIB', 'QJC', 'RKD', 'SLE', 'TMF', 'UNG']
```